# storing image in MySQL to display in Android listview advice

Tags: android, mysql, image, store

I need some advice. I am doing a grocery list app on the android platform. I am planning to add product images and name to the listview. I am using MySQL and php(using XAMPP localhost) to display the data. So far i was successful with the text display using AndroidHive's connect tutorial.

My question is how should i store the images:

1. Upload the images to the database using datatype BLOPB
   or
2. Transfer the image to the localhost(htdocs) folder then store directory path(using varchar datatype) [not sure if its possible but I have done something similar in asp.net]

I have seen some example here but not too sure which would be easier for me(beginner level). Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you store images to localhost and use the associated localtion in db.

Because, converting image files and then storing it database would be difficult.
On the other half, it would affect your DB size a lot.

Storing data at localhost would be effective as the size of local disk is not a problem. Moreover, you will have access to image files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was considering that too.. And probably more overhead when displaying the image in the app. Thnaks